# Tkinter - key-binding to frame won't work if a child widget gets focus

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, key-bindings

I'm trying to write a program with different key-binds for different frames.

This works fine if the frame is put into focus, but if another widget is put into focus, the key-bind does not work.

For example, in this trial code, the key bind will work if no widget is in focus, but if the button is put into focus (either programatically or through using the TAB wkey to focus the button), then the key bind on the frame no longer works. Setting the focus on the frame, after setting it on the button widget does not help.

```
import tkinter as tk


class TestGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.edit_text = tk.StringVar()

        self.intro_label = tk.Label(self, text="Press button to say Hello")
        self.hello_button = tk.Button(self, text='Say Hello (H)', command=self.press_button)
        self.text_area = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.edit_text, width=20, height=5)

        self.intro_label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        self.hello_button.pack(pady=5)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=10, pady=(5, 10))

        self.bind('<Key>', self.press_key)
        self.hello_button.focus()
        self.focus()

    def press_button(self):
        txt = self.edit_text.get()
        txt += "Hello World!\n"
        self.edit_text.set(txt)

    def press_key(self, event):
        key_pressed = event.char.lower()
        if key_pressed == "h":
            self.hello_button.invoke()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    TestGUI(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I know that the key bind will still work if I put the bind on the application level:

`parent.bind('<Key>', self.press_key)`

However, I want to use different key binds on different frames in the application. Is there a way to do this, without losing the key bind if another widget gains focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, that's not a feature that tkinter has. Binding to a window is a special case that allows any child in the window react to the bind.

It sounds like you want to use a different key for every frame? So the first frame responds to 'h', and the second to 's' or something? In that case you can simply bind each frame to exactly what you want, instead of all keys. This also avoids the need for a second method to invoke the button press:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TestGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.edit_text = tk.StringVar()

        self.intro_label = tk.Label(self, text="Press button to say Hello")
        self.hello_button = tk.Button(self, text='Say Hello (H)', command=self.press_button)
        self.text_area = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.edit_text, width=20, height=5)

        self.intro_label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        self.hello_button.pack(pady=5)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=10, pady=(5, 10))

        self.bind_all('<h>', self.press_button) # bind to the 'h' key
        # ~ parent.bind('<h>', self.press_button) # alternative way
        self.hello_button.focus()
        self.focus()

    def press_button(self, event=None):
        txt = self.edit_text.get()
        txt += "Hello World!\n"
        self.edit_text.set(txt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    TestGUI(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Otherwise I suppose you could make a quick loop to bind to all the children in a frame.

```
def set_child_bind(widget, event, callback):
    widget.bind(event, callback)
    for child in widget.children.values():
        set_child_bind(child, event, callback)

class TestGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # all the other stuff
        set_child_bind(self, '<Key>', self.press_key)
```

Or you could use the FocusIn event to grab application-wide binding:

```
class TestGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # all the other stuff
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e:self.bind_all('<Key>', self.press_key))
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e:self.unbind_all('<Key>'))
```

Comment: Thank you @Novel. bind_all and <FocusIn> <FocusOut> look useful. I guess the only thing this doesn't allow is if you wanted, say the 'h' key to do something different depending on which frame you were looking at. I saw the child method before, but it looked a little clunky!

Comment: @Andrew all of these methods let you tweak the action of the 'h' key by using an instance variable in the press_button method, similar to how you set which widget to add the text to. As a first example, use `txt += f"Hello from {self}!\n"`